# best way to promote git local repository (cloned from) to origin to use with git-tf

Tags: git, tfs, repository, move, git-tf

I'm using Git-tf to (obviously) skip TFS and be able to work offline and avoid the readonlys and all that tune ...
Now .. I started cloning the tfs project in to lets say drive D: then I cloned again from drive c: (I think i was over paranoid there)

My current workflow is to commit the changes (in repo c:) to repo D: and then push the checkins to TFS

It works fine but it gets messy and I think I'm over complicating the workflow

What would be the best ?

could I configure the repo c: to point straight to TFS ... and remove native git origin (repo d:)
Copy repo d: to c: and continue (I tried that and it works fine locally , but I didn't commit any changes yet to TFS)
can I promote the repo c: to be ORIGIN (as in D:) and then continue to push changes to TFS from there (after git-tf config) ? ...not sure about this promote thing ...

Also: having in mind the project(as in C# vs2012)  its a big project that is not that straight forward re-configure and build) not even mention to wait for the copy process :) .
Any Other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot configure repo `C:` to point straight to TFS.  Repository `D:` contains the data about the git commit to TFS changeset mappings that were created when you fetched/cloned the repository.  Without this data, `git-tf` cannot build a delta between the last changeset you fetched and your current commit in order to create a TFS changeset.

Copying `D:` to `C:` should be fine, as it will copy over the `git-tf` metadata that's stored in the git repository.

I don't know what you mean by "promote `C:` to `D:`".  If you cloned `C:` from `D:`, you could make changes and push them back to `D:` and then `git-tf checkin` them.  It doesn't really matter where the new git commits come from, if your `HEAD` points to a commit that is a child or grandchild of a commit that was created from the latest TFS changeset, `git-tf` can build a new changeset of the differences.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll keep the workflow as c:[repo] => d:[repo] => TFS
It will allow me in the future to share the code from with my coleages if they wish to try Git and they see the value on it